# How should I split up the test values?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently working on a program in Qt/C++ that will analyse and test differents values received from a device called "Phabrix SxE". These values will have different limits depending on which product we're testing.

My first thought was to create a class named something like "TestLimits", with private variables for all of the values that we'll test. This class would then be used in i class called "TestConfiguration" (which will, besides the "TestLimits" class, hold information about what IP adress, port and name that the Phabrix device has).

```
TestConfiguration (name, ip, port, limits);
```

If I use this strategy, I would need to use getters and setters for **every private member value** in the TestLimits class. I'm not a real fan of getters/setters, just because they break encapsulation. If I instead only use the "TestConfiguration" class and declare all of the limits right in the constructor parameters...

```
TestConfiguration (name, ip, port, limit1, limit2, limit3, ..., ...);
```

... it would get messy pretty fast.

How can I avoid getters, setters and long, messy constructors when creating something like this? Even if I use the "TestLimit" I would need to declare them like this...

```
TestLimit(limit1, limit2, limit3, ..., ..., ...);
```

... which is still quite messy. And what if I need to add a new value to one of the test? In that scenario I would have needed to edit every row where TestLimit constructor is used.

Anyone done something similar and can throw me some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Pass a `std::vector` as the limits. I would expect you would store them as a vector as well.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the limits from a file: XML or JSON or .ini (QSettings). That way you don't need to have hard-to-maintain parameters lists in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for your situation depends on the design goals for the rest of the software.  Some example questions that I would use to guide design choices:

- How many limits, and are they all the same data type or different?
- How are they referred to?  That is, are they literally "limit 1, limit 2, ..." or "max voltage, max current, ...?"
- Do the number or layout of limits change frequently?  Is this something that is small now, but may scale as the program evolves?
- How does the software learn what the limits are?  Do they come from configuration file, user dialog, hard coded, or something else?

Below are some possibilities that may or may not be best suited to your particular situation.

---

#### Option 1:  Plain Old struct

If the problem is false encapsulation from boilerplate getters and setters, maybe it is best to get rid of them:

```
struct TestLimits {
    voltage max_voltage;
    current max_current;
    limit limit3;
};
```

This allows you to refer to each limit by a meaningful name in the source code, and it eliminates any tedious constructor, getter, and setter code.  It may be harder to make limits more complex later.  For instance, if a new test is added to the software later, so that `max_voltage` is now a function of `test_time`, then everything that touches TestLimits has to change.

#### Option 2:  Only have getters to preserve encapsulation

Suppose that test limits are computed all at once through some intensive operation, like reading a configuration file, or querying a test device.  I frequently end up with a pattern like this:

```
class TestLimitsFinder {
public:
    TestLimitsFinder();

    void find_all_the_limits();

    const voltage& max_voltage() const;
    const current& max_current() const;
    limit limit3() const;

private:
    voltage max_voltage_;
    current max_current_;
    limit limit3_;
};
```

This system offers some encapsulation.  The only way to set limits is through the `find_all_the_limits()` method.  It eliminates boilerplate constructors and setters, but not getters.  If there are many objects that consume limits, but only one or a few that produce the limits, then the getter methods could be offered as an abstract `ITestLimits` interface.  Then all of the consumers of limits don't know how the software finds them.  That part of the implementation could change entirely without changing the all of the users.

#### Option 3:  QProperty

Qt has a [property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) that can be quite useful for objects that are parameterizable.  If you use QProperties, it becomes very easy to produce dialogs to obtain the properties / limits, and there is also an XML serialization system, among other things.  Properties have a lot of flexibility in terms of whether to write custom getters, setters, and notification signals.  It is also possible to dynamically add or modify properties for an object at runtime.

On the other hand, the `TestLimits` container has to derive from `QObject`, which introduces the meta-object compiler.  This introduces deep Qt dependencies into the limits code, which may not be suitable.